# Ionic and Angularjs - form binding appears to be only one way.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've a list of items. They are objects held in itemArray. When you touch one you it fires ng-click="openEditor(item)". Like this:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in ItemArray" class="item item-avatar" ng-click="openEditor(item)">
    <img ng-src="{{iconMap[item.type]}}">
    <h2>{{item.dateString}}</h2><span>{{item.startTimeString}}</span>
    <p>ASA {{item.priority}}: {{item.itemType}}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Then this happens:

```
$scope.openEditor =function(item){ 
   $scope.currentItem = item;
   $scope.modal.show();
}
```

and in the modal I have

```
<select ng-model="currentItem.priority">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
```

It shows the correct priority in the dropdown (I've tested it with a lot of the items).

The problem is - I cannot change it! If I try I can't alter the option in the dropdown.

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'priority' of #<Object>
```

Why is this happening? I want to change the priority and then save it back into the itemArray and SQL DB.

Comment: It's look good for me http://plnkr.co/edit/I2K78UDxUWq9YCeFuSoj?p=preview     please try to add some plunker to illustrate the problem

Comment: It must have something to do with the modal then. Your example seems fine but when in the modal I cannot change the items. I can't recreate it on Plunker as it'll mean rebuilding the entire app get all the dependencies in. It's an Ionic app so that means using Ionic and getting the modal template and so on.

Comment: From my experience, those problem are always related to 'isolated scope problem', please check if 'currentItem.priority' refer to the same scope you are working (maybe angular added isolated scope that you can't see)

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be it. I'm not sure how to work around it though. How do I ensure that the scope of the modal can see the other scope of the currentItem?

Comment: Did you pass the `$scope` to the modal? `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });`

Comment: Yes I did. That's all there.

Comment: I've updated the question with the error I get in the console when I try to change things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the object you're trying to change is read-only. You need to investigate why this is, but you could make a copy of the object with

```
$scope.openEditor =function(item){ 
   $scope.currentItem = angular.copy(item);
   $scope.modal.show();
}
```